# Find the limit of $a_n=\frac{\sqrt[n]{n^n +cn}}{cn+c/(n+1)}$ with $c>0$.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

> Find the limit of $a_n=\frac{\sqrt[n]{n^n +cn}}{cn+c/(n+1)}$ with $c>0$.

---

I'm sorry to post such a (probably) trivial problem, but I'm just not seeing it. My best shot at it was:

$$\frac{\sqrt[n]{n^n +cn}}{cn+c/(n+1)}=\frac{\sqrt[n]{n^{n-1} +c}\cdot\sqrt[n]{n}}{c(n+\frac{1}{n+1})}\longrightarrow\frac{1\cdot\infty}{\infty}=\infty.$$

I have officially no knowledge of calculus yet, meaning no Taylor series expansion.

Comment: Try $$\frac{n\cdot\sqrt[n]{1+c/n^{n-1}}}{c\cdot n\cdot(1+1/(n(n+1)))}$$

Comment: @Did How does that help me? Still not seeing it, sorry.

Comment: @math_mu: Cancel $n$ first. The expression under the $n$-th root in the nominator goes to 1 when n goes to infinitity. The same is true for the $n$-th root. In denominator, the expression in brackets also goes to 1. So you are left with only $c$ in the denominator. And you're done.

Answer (score 2):

$$
a_n=\frac{\sqrt[n]{n^n +cn}}{cn+c/(n+1)} = \frac{(n+1)n\sqrt[n]{1+c n^{-(n-1)}}}{c((n+1)n+1)} = \frac{\sqrt[n]{1+c n^{-(n-1)}}}{c(1+\frac{1}{(n+1)n})}
$$

hence

$$
\lim_{n\to \infty}a_n = \frac{1}{c}
$$